# How's "in moments such as we observed" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

> The professors in these more “conversational” classes
> do more frequently encourage the students to occupy different sides of a debate,
> perhaps those of the parties in the case, or of different policy positions pertinent
> to the case, and so forth. In this sense, the students are drawn into occupying a
> role that is generally taken by the professor in the more Socratic classes, in which
> the teacher frequently winds up taking one position and casting his or her student
> interlocutor in the other. This does happen in the more conversational short-exchange
> classes as well, all of which, as noted, contain some more traditional
> Socratic dialogue. But **in moments such as we observed [embolding mine]** in the previous transcript
> excerpt, a polyphony of voices joins in exploring and explicating the issues raised
> by the case under discussion.

[Elizabeth Mertz](https://secure.law.wisc.edu/profiles/emertz@abfn.org), *The Language of Law School: Learning to "Think Like a Lawyer"* (2007), p 158. Mertz graduated BA (Bryn Mawr College) and PhD (Duke University) in Anthropology, JD (Northwestern University School of Law, *Magna cum Laude*, Order of the Coif, graduated first in class). I recapitulated her academic letters to substantiate that Mertz is literate in English and highly educated, and that this isn't a typo.

This instantiation of "such as" feels ungrammatical to me. This prepositional phrase WOULD BE grammatical if we added [those that]

1. in moments such as [those that] we observed

or if we relocated the SUCH to before "moments"

2. in **such** moments as we observed

Answer (score 2):

The writer may be well educated and literate, but that does not guarantee a style that all will find attractive.

Ellipsis is allowed by English grammar

> moments such as we observed

is just as grammatical as

> moments such as those we observed

or

> moments such as those that we observed

Now personally I do not like the style used. I might write it

> In instances like those in the previous excerpt, a polyphony…

But that is about style rather than grammar.

Comment: You wrote that "moments such as we observed" is just as grammatical as "moments such as those we observed". Can you please expatiate why the former "is just as grammatical"? It isn't to me.

Comment: Grammar is how the language is actually used. Ellipsis is a common feature of English. Ellipsis is not ungrammatical. You personally may elect not to use it. You may not like its use by others. Those are aspects of style, of taste, rather than grammar. As you said, the writer is well educated and with a doctorate in a field dependent on the careful use of words. I too do not like the author’s prose, but my dislike does not make it ungrammatical.

Comment: A bit of a nitpick:  Ellipsis *in certain situations* is not ungrammatical (you can't just ellipsize anything you want to, of course).  However, in this case, "such as (verb clause)" is a well-established and generally accepted construction (this is more commonly done with passive voice, but active voice is also acceptable if the meaning is unambiguous), so I do agree that this is entirely grammatically correct.  Grammar is actually *what is generally accepted* as correct by *English speakers as a whole*, so it's not really about any individual's feelings on the matter.

Comment: @Foogod Yes, I agree. Some forms of ellipsis are grammatical; some are not. It depends on usage. Thank you for the clarification. Do you think an edit to my answer is warranted?

Comment: No, I think your answer is fine, I was just nitpicking on your follow-up comment, mostly, and didn't want somebody to get the idea that it's a general rule that you can leave out anything anywhere :)